# jQuery add onkeypress doesn't work if use @Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

My problem is the follow: I use jQuery to add attribute to input, but if this input is generate with @Html.TextBoxFor, the jQuery code doesn´t work... This works if I use input tag.

My jQuery code:

```
$('#ElementId').attr('onkeypress', 'return MyFunction();');
```

In the page:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyText, new { @class = "Inputcss", id = "ElementId"})
```

UPDATE

The html code:

```
<input id="ElementId" name="MyText" type="text" value="" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" class="valid">
```

The 'jQuery' is executed successfully., and recognizes the element.

I know there are other ways to add by jquery and works, but I want to know what is the reason because 'attr' does not work.

thanks for any help!

sorry for my english, if someone corrects the wording thank you.

Comment: you haven't used the ID **#ElementId** in the Html helper. Is that a typo??

Comment: @Samy S.Rathore Sorry, is example code, but yes I put the id, I update the question. Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the rendered html to make sure the ID is being changed, and is not `MyText`?

Comment: Yes, the id is "ElementId" in the browser

Comment: Ok, where is your `MyFunction()` placed??

Comment: It's working in this fiddle I created http://jsfiddle.net/Vhc8z/3/, did you place the attr call inside of a ready function?

Comment: @Samy S.Rathore I debug the jquery and does not reach this function

Comment: @Smeegs yes, the function are in redy, how weird is that it does not work for more I run it in the browser console. yes, your jsfiddle works but if I use <input> instead of Html.TextBoxFor works too

Comment: It's apparent that the problem is somewhere else.  You need to post more code.  Since we've isolated the functionality and learned that the approach works, something else must be breaking it.  Something that isn't posted.

Comment: For my curiosity, can you post the rendered html?

Comment: @Smeegs If may be that the problem is in some other hand, I'm investigating, but is rare. Ok, in a few minutes I update the question with that information.Thanks

Comment: It IS wierd, if you place the code in a separate function in the JS section, it does not work, [see updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vhc8z/5/)(JsFiddle places this code in the head section). BUT if you take the code and place it in the html section, [It works](http://jsfiddle.net/Vhc8z/6/)(placed in the body)

Comment: @SamyS.Rathore, that's a jsfiddle thing.  By default the js is added in the load method so the function only exists in the scope of `load`. To change this you just need to change it in the dropdown on the left from `onload` to `No wrap - in <head>` [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Vhc8z/7/)

Comment: @Smeegs Oh yeah, that did the trick, definitely working fine. The problem must be somewhere else

Comment: Indeed it was something external .... I did another test project and works, I'll have to see what is affecting me. Thank you very much for all the ideas! And sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Nacho, yeah, something is up as the attribute isn't being added at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was versioned jQuery. Sorry for the inconvenience.